# How can I add inlines to the ModelAdmin of another app, without a circular dependency?

Tags: django, django-admin, encapsulation

Let's say I have two models, in different apps.  App Two knows about app One, but not the other way around:

```
# one/models.py

from django.db import models

class One(models.Model):
    pass


# two/models.py

from django.db import models
from one.models import One

class Two(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(One)
```

I also have `One` registered in the admin site:

```
# one/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import One

admin.site.register(One)
```

How do I register `Two` as an Inline on `One`'s admin page, without introducing a circular dependency between the two apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply, providing you don't mind accessing a 'private' attribute on the `ModelAdmin`. (Attributes beginning with an underscore are treated as private by convention.)

```
# two/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from one.models import One
from .models import Two

class TwoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Two

admin.site._registry[One].inlines.append(TwoInline)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but solved it more gentle way.

```
# one/admin.py

class OneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = One

admin.site.register(One, OneAdmin)
```

---

```
# two/admin.py

class TwoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Two

import one.admin
class OneAdmin(one.admin.OneAdmin):
    inlines = [TwoInline]

admin.site.unregister(One)
admin.site.register(One, OneAdmin)
```

As you see I extended the original ModelAdmin from first app and added inlines from second app. Don't forget to unregister the model from first app before registering it again. 
It's safe and much better than to access private member of the class as was suggested.

Comment: this solution is good in that it only uses public methods, but it's also inherently brittle, since only one descendant app can do this: if a second descendant app (`three`) were to try to do this, it would clobber the registration of `two`'s inline. To avoid this, `three` would have to know about the `two` app and register both inlines (which introduces the same type of cross-dependency that this question is trying to avoid). For this reason, the solution of appending to the inlines list seems preferable (even though I agree it's not great to be poking around in attributes marked as "private")

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
# one/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from one.models import One
from two.models import Two

class TwoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Two

class OneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TwoInline,]

admin.site.register(One, OneAdmin)
```

You can read more at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin).

Comment: This is just the standard way of registering the app.  This question is about avoiding a circular dependency between the two apps - in your example, each app knows about the other.

Comment: All right, I see. Your example is something like a "hot plug". Thank you for showing something new and very interesting.